# How to setup Xtion Pro Live Ubuntu 14.04 openNI(1/2)?

Tags: kinect, openni, ubuntu, xtion, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the right way to setup Xtion Pro Live with Ubuntu 14.04? (later on I wanrt to use it with ROS)
All How-To's found in internet refer to http://openni.org which is down.
The new site for openNI2 is http://structure.io/openni but the information provieded there does not help me.
I tried many things but seems to be that I'm to stupid to get it to work.
What I'm doing wrong, what should I do?

What do I need? openNI1 or openNI2?
Do I need to install with apt-get or build from source.
Do I need to install this sensor driver: https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor (building fails for some reason).
I'm totally desperate and confused due to the both version 1 and 2 from openNI.

// Here is my connected sensor

pat@hostx:~/Sensor$ lsusb | grep ASUS
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1d27:0601 ASUS

// Here is the sample I used

pat@hostx:~/OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2/Samples/Bin$ ./SimpleRead
Couldn't open device
DeviceOpen using default: no devices found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190377/how-to-setup-xtion-pro-live-ubuntu-14.04-openni(1/2)-?/) by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Xtion 0601 runs using openni2, and 0600 runs using openni. If you want to use the former with ROS, let the [openni2_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_launch) wrapper run the driver and setup all the topics for you. It will also install all the correct dependencies:

`sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni2-launch`

If you're looking for Openni2 specific documentation, it's now hosted by Occipital (http://structure.io/openni).

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) on 2014-08-16**:
THX sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni2-launch solved the issue for ID 1d27:0601. Then afterwards roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-10-29**:
I'm trying to set up an rgb stream to my web browser using mjpeg_server and openni2 with Asus Xtion Pro Live. I ran `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch`,`rosrun mjpeg_server mjpeg_server`, but I can't see anything on my web browser when I type in the url http://myurl.com:port/image_topic. Help!

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-29**:
Please open a new question instead of doing this. Include any error/debug output, your distro and hardware setup.

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-10-29**:
Please see http://answers.ros.org/question/196270/stream-asus-xtion-pro-live-rgb-with-openni2-and-mjpeg_server/ !

**Comment by [VinceDietrich](https://answers.ros.org/users/14941/vincedietrich/) on 2015-06-25**:
My 0600 xtion only works with openni2, but not with openni